# hiding next and previous buttons from a single image in carousel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, carousel

I am working on a website in which I want to place next and previous buttons on images so that its easy for the users to navigate through the images.

The php code which I have used with carousel classes are:

```
<div class="text-center border-right px-0">
   <div id="owl_item_images" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <?php
         if(isset($data['item']->media))
         {
         foreach ($data['item']->media as $media)
         {
         echo '<div class="item">
         <div class="item_image_wrapper mx-auto">
         <img class="item_images_carousel" src="'.$media->url.'">
         </div>
         </div>';
         //'.$media->url.';
         }
         }
         ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

The HTML code rendered at the front end is:

```
   <div id="owl_item_images" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
      <div class="owl-stage-outer owl-height" style="height: 350px;">
         <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-7677px, 0px, 0px); transition: 1.5s; width: 8530px;">
            <div class="owl-item">
               <div class="item">
                  <div class="item_image_wrapper mx-auto">
                     <img class="item_images_carousel" src=".jpg">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="owl-item">
               ---
            </div>

            <div class="owl-item">
               ---
            </div>

            <div class="owl-item">
               ---
            </div>

            <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 853px;">
               <div class="item">
                  <div class="item_image_wrapper mx-auto">
                     <img class="item_images_carousel" src=".jpg">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-nav disabled">
         <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
         <div class="owl-next">next</div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-dots">
         <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
         <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
         <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
          -
          -
          -
          -           
         <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Problem Statement:

I am wondering what changes I should do in the PHP code (as html code is rendered at the front end) above so that previous/next buttons are visible.

On removing display none I can see next and previous buttons but I am wondering still how I can hide next and previous buttons when there is a single image in the carousel.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="owl-nav disabled">
             <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
             <div class="owl-next">next</div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled, .owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled {
    /* display: none; */
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Don't remove/comment `display: none;` from the CSS.  Instead, remove the `disabled` class from the element if you don't want it disabled.

Comment: @PatrickQ the html code is getting rendered at the front end. Only changes I can do is in the php code and css I think.  I have posted HTML code as well to get more clear picture.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I will do that. I am wondering if you can give me a pointer for this question.

Comment: You can use Javascript/jQuery to remove the class.  Again, you do _not_ want to edit the plugin's CSS.  Also, the plugin probably has a setting for whether or not the nav is visible by default.

Comment: @flash I'm afraid I don't understand your question at all. Read: *`how I can hide next and previous buttons from a single image.`* thumbs up if you understand ;) You mean... you want to hide the buttons when **-there's only ONE image**?? Isn't owl carousel already supposed to do that? Have you explored their documentation?

Comment: @PatrickQ Are you able to understand my q ? Just checking.

Comment: Yes, I understand perfectly. However, you don't seem to want to listen to what I'm telling you.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes I am listening to you.

Comment: I didn't edit the CSS plugin. I just override the CSS but I will use javascript/jquery now. Sorry !

Comment: See [the options](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html) for this plugin.  There is a `nav` option.  The default is to hide it.

Comment: @PatrickQ Just checked the link. I am wondering how I can implement in the current code.

Comment: @PatrickQ I am sorry if I am asking silly questions. I haven't worked on owl carousel before.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I have found this [solution](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1519) on internet but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @flash the `onInitialize` (from the link you found) is just a function that you can include/add when defining your settings object. Search the carousel docs for the `onInitialize` and how to modify the defaults by passing custom settings to the Owl carousel instantiation object.

Comment: If you search your project you'll find `.owlCarousel({` <<< inside those `{}` place your `onInitialized` function as described here: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1519

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding "**I am wondering still how I can hide next and previous buttons from a single image**". Is it the case that you want to hide the next and previous buttons from view when a particular image is on display? e.g. the fourth image in the carousel. Or is it the case that you want those buttons to appear only if there is more than one image on the carousel?

Comment: @DanNagle Your last point. I want buttons to appear only if there is more than one image on the carousel.

Comment: @DanNagle If there is only one image in the carousel then no next and previous buttons should appear.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) there is a `change.owl.carousel` event to change the options.

```
$('#owl_item_images').trigger('change.owl.carousel', { nav: true });
```

EDIT: You can update the JavaScript in the [custom.js](https://search.ruckify.com/js/custom.js) file. The code below includes the `nav` property and sets its value to `true`.

```
// Items page items images carousel [Line # 62]
var owlItemImages = $('#owl_item_images');
owlItemImages.owlCarousel({
    items: 1, 
    nav: true, // enable the nav buttons
    dots: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1,
            loop:false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In order to clear my question. This is the [website](https://search.ruckify.com/item/cf90a1e0-5753-11e8-8726-8765ee31d6e8) on which I am working on. I want `next and previous buttons to show up when there are multiple images in the carousel` and when there is `no image in the carousel, no next and previous buttons should show`.